# Rails: how to treat alternative Accept: content-types as JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-type

So far I've found two ways for `request.format.json?` to be true in Rails (i.e. where the incoming request is treated as JSON).  One is if you request a resource and ending in `.json` the other is if you supply the header `Accept: application/json` in your request.  Each work stand-alone.

I want to register my own "accepts" type for this second case:

**`Accept: application/vnd.myapp_v1+json`**  and have this treated by rails as a "json request" like `application/json`, without the need to append `.json`.

My first thought was to register my own MimeType as `:json` (within my initialisation code), but this will actually break support for application/json, not what I want to do.

```
    Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.myapp_v1+json", :json  # my failed attempt
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We move iPhone requests over to HTML in our app with a before_filter like so:

```
before_filter :determine_format

def determine_format
    request.format = :iphone if (request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] =~ /iPhone/ && request.format == :html)
end
```

I imagine you can do something similar with your specific format, maybe like this:

```
def determine_format
    request.format = :json if (request.format == 'application/vnd.myapp_v1+json')
end
```

Answer (score 10):

An alternative to this is:

```
api_mime_types = %W(
  application/vnd.api+json
  text/x-json
  application/json
)

Mime::Type.unregister :json
Mime::Type.register 'application/json', :json, api_mime_types
```

In `initializers/mime_types.rb`.