# jQuery File Upload and Internet Explorer: "script" requested as "html"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, file-upload

I'm using [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) with Ruby on Rails 3

```
$(".jquery-upload").fileupload({
    url: "/photos",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "script" });
```

Works as supposed in Chrome and other browsers, but IE sends the request as HTML rather than JS:

```
Started POST "/photos"
Processing by PhotosController#create as HTML
```

Changing "url" to "/photos.js" to force JS format resulted in IE prompting to download the returned JS instead of processing it.

How can I make IE request "script" and process it as JS?

Comment: Is you response returning a javascript content-type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem answer seems to be explained in your plugin's documentation : https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup

Look at the `Content-Type Negotiation` paragraph.

Comment: This sounds right, but I'm not sure how to implement what I need in Rails

Comment: how should we do that in rails ?

Comment: I'm not good at Rails but have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388082/rails-how-to-treat-alternative-accept-content-types-as-json

The PHP solution shouldn't be hard to transcript to Rails with that.

Comment: For the record: For me, IE8 raised an 'unexpected identifier' exception, which was resolved by adding `render(json: "", content_type: request.format)`, like the link suggested.